# Custom UITableViewCell Doesn't Draw Corectly

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I'm having a really weird issue with my custom UITableViewCell. I have a cell with an identifier of "ThreadCell" in Interface Builder with some custom labels. These labels are tagged so I can access them.

In my code, I am doing the following:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ThreadCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"ThreadCell"];
}

Person *person = [self.people objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 0];
nameLabel.text = person.nickname;

return cell;
```

This seems to work fine, with one exception. The TableView draws like this:

[image: Cells]

This obviously isn't my custom cell. But the weird thing is, when I *tap* on a cell, I get this:

[image: Cells]

This *is* my custom cell, drawn *behind* the default cell. *What?!* I'm not sure how this is happening because I do not ever set the title of the textview anywhere, so I'm not sure where the first John Smith comes from.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you allocate a plain `UITableViewCell` and not an instance of your custom cell. Setting a `reuseIdentifier` in `initWithStyle` is not sufficient to load an instance of a custom cell class.

If you develop for iOS 5 and later, then you can use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` to register a NIB file containing your custom cell. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will then always return an instance of that NIB.

Comment: Thanks. I have the custom cell in my main storyboard. Should I separate the cell out into its own Nib?

Comment: @AndrewM: I think with Storyboard it is even easier: Set the "Identifier" of the prototype cell of the table view to "ThreadCell". Then you don't need the `registerNib:...` call.

Comment: @AndrewM: Could it be that you have more than one prototype cell in the table view?

Comment: Nope-- the table has Prototype Cells set to 1 in IB and I only see one prototype cell in the actual IB canvas.

Comment: @AndrewM: Strange. - You select the `nameLabel` with `[cell viewWithTag: 0]`. For a standard cell this would return the standard `textLabel`. You could try to use a different tag number, e.g. 17, just to narrow down the problem. - And I still wonder about the overlapping cells in your second image. Perhaps you could add a screenshot of the Storyboard setup to your question?

Comment: Good catch on the tags! Fixing that actually fixed the entire thing. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much for catching a stupid mistake on my part! It's always the little things :)